# Scripts for generating csv files for spark Canssandra data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I want to generate the 'csv' files as per below logic for the table in cassandra.

`val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a",1,"abc@gmail.com"), ("b",2,"def@gmail.com"),("a",1,"xyz@gmail.com"),("a",2,"abc@gmail.com"))).toDF("col1","col2","emailId")`

I want to generate the 'csv' files as per below logic.
Since there are 3 distinct 'emailid's' I need to generate 3 distinct 'csv' files.

Three csv files for below 3 different queries.

`select * from table where emailId='abc@gmail.com'
select * from table where emailId='def@gmail.com'
select * from table where emailId='xyz@gmail.com'`
How can I do this. Can anyone please help me on this.

Version:
Spark 1.6.2
Scala 2.10

Comment: Analysis: I know if I have a dataframe I can save it to csv format like below. `df.write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(path)` But I want to iterate through the loop and generate the csv file for each emailId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a distinct list of the emails then iterate over them. When iterating, filter for only the emails that match and save the dataframe to Cassandra.

```
import sql.implicits._
val emailData = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a",1,"abc@gmail.com"), ("b",2,"def@gmail.com"),("a",1,"xyz@gmail.com"),("a",2,"abc@gmail.com"))).toDF("col1","col2","emailId")
val distinctEmails = emailData.select("emailId").distinct().as[String].collect
for (email <- distinctEmails){
    val subsetEmailsDF = emailData.filter($"emailId" === email).coalesce(1)
    //... Save the subset dataframe to cassandra
}
```

Note: coalesce(1) sends all the data to one node. This can create memory issues if the dataframe is too large.

Comment: @ Jeremy, thanks for your response...  your above should be helping me for sure. Even I was trying to collect the list of emailid's and iterate through it like below `df.select("emailId").distinct.collectAsList()`.

Comment: Actually I need to save the dataframe to csv file in each iteration, need not save to Cassandra. Your code should help. Thanks

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If the answer satisfies your question please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.